# Why the function definition foo(int i+=1) is not possible?

Tags: c++, function, arguments

In the function

```
int foo(int i, int j)
{
    return i + j;
}
```

both `i` and `j` are uninitialized, so this function could be called with and only with two arguments:

```
foo(5, 6); // 11
```

Okay, but C++ featured **default parameters**, and made possible definitions like:

```
int foo(int i = 1, int j = 2)
{
    return i + j;
}
```

Here both `i` and `j` has default arguments, then calls:

```
foo(5, 6); // 11
foo(5); // 7
foo(); // 3
```

are possible. So then, why this definition:

```
int foo(int i += 1, int j += 2)
{
    return i + j;
}
```

And these calls:

```
foo(5, 6); // 14
foo(5); // 8
foo(); // 3
```

are impossible? Is it difficult to represent this definition or the calls causes some problems? I want to know.

Comment: it does not make any sense to me.

Comment: One reason is that `int i += 42;` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Yeah pretty much because they make no sense.

Comment: Because that's how the language is defined.  Moreover, what would be the point?

Comment: Makes as much sense as a boat in pajamas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declarations (with or without initializers) and assignments are different things, even if there are some similarities in the syntax.

This:

```
int i;
```

declares a variable `i` of type `int`.  This:

```
int i = 42;
```

does the same and specifies its initial value `42`.

This:

```
i = 42;
```

looks a lot like the declaration with the initializer, but it assigns the value `42` to an *existing* variable which has to have been declared previously.  This:

```
i += 42;
```

is a *compound assignment*, essentially equivalent to `i = i + 42;`.

Initialization is similar to a *simple* assignment, not to a *compound* assignment.  An initializer specifies the initial value of a variable by providing an expression to be evaluated and stored in the variable. You can't just have arbitrary expressions and statements in that context.

If you want to have a parameter whose value is, say, 2 greater than the value passed as an argument, you can do that within the function:

```
int foo(int i, int j)
{
    i ++;
    j += 2;
    return i + j;
}
```

though that cases is more clearly and simply written as:

```
int foo(int i, int j)
{
    return i + j + 3;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer differs from "no because of no".

Comment: Actually, `int i;` ___[defines](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1410632/140719)___ a variable.

Comment: @sbi: Yes, it defines a variable. It also declares it.

Comment: @Keith: Yes, you are human. You are also an ape. (If someone came along who couldn't tell a human from a monkey, would consider it accurate to be introduced as an ape?)

Comment: @sbi: I didn't think the distinction was very important in this context, and guessed that "declares" might be clearer than "defines" to the OP. If I were going for language-lawyer levels of precision (which I often do), I would have written "object" rather than "variable".

Answer (score 6):

Because it makes no sense.  It's one thing to assign a value, it's another to increment a pre-existing value.  What would you expect the value of `i` to be in this (invalid) code snippet?

```
// huh?
int i += 12;
```

`i` never had a value, so it makes no sense to add to it.